# v-select not showing data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried my code on a codepen and it works fine.. You can see the code here: [My codepen](https://codepen.io/Trimakas/pen/JaboaB)

However, it doesn't work in my code locally. Meaning the data isn't displayed in the drop down like it does in the CodePen. I think its a versioning issue, but I can't find any info on what the latest versions should be.. This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "refactor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Complete refactor",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "country-list": "^1.1.0",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^1.1.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the `v-select` isn't grabbing the data from `marketplaces`. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have another version of the exact same code that IS displaying the data in the select. The only difference is the versions in `package.json`. I just don't want to be stuck on a specific version of either Vue or Vuetify. But here is the working `package.json` file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-loader": "14.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }
}
```

Comment: @raina77ow sorry, its not displaying the data in the select box.

Comment: And there's no error in console?

Comment: @raina77ow not a one! it just isn't showing the data in the select. In fact I have another version of the exact same code and it is working, but the package.json versions are different. I'll post the other version in the OP.

Comment: There is no vue-select in your package.json